# How to prevent ListView with two columns from drawing to the size of ArrayList passed (prevent populating empty items)?

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I have a custom ListView Adaper that has two columns. It accepts an ArrayList and populate its content in two columns. 
My adapter class is like this

```
public class myAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String []> {
    private final Activity activity;
    private final ArrayList<String []> myArray;
    public  myAdapter(Activity activity,ArrayList<String[]> arraylist){
        super(activity,R.layout.customListview,arraylist);
        this.activity = activity;
        this.myArray = arraylist;
}
@Override
public View getView(final int position,View view, ViewGroup parent){
    LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customListview, null, true);

    if (position < (myArray.size()/2)){
        textview1.setText(myArray.get(position*2)[0]);
        textview2.setText(myArray.get((position*2)+1)[0]);
    }
    else {
        LinearLayout listRow = (LinearLayout)rowView.findViewById(R.id.listRow);
        listRow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        textvew1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        textvew2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    return rowView;
}
```

My listview is displaying contents properly. But there is a blank space below my listview. I think it is populating null elements with list item for the size of the array passed. Since I am displaying the contents of my array in two columns,  I need the size of listview to be only the half of my array. Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.[This happens if i pass array with 2 elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5Nux.png)

Here is the customListview.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listRow"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">
        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: create class with 2 members (value1, value2) assume `MyData` and use it in your adapter, pass ArrayList<MyData> to the adapterm then getItem by `position` is better than this caculation and skipping empty, ... etc other problems you may face.

Comment: myarray is of type  ArrayList<String[]> it fetches data from a json object that is the result of some get request. and string[] contains about 7 data. that is why I used an ArrayList of type String Array

Comment: i noticed you are hosting String[] in each arraylist item, my point is you need to get rid of things like this: `myArray.get(position*2)` and `(myArray.size()/2)` ... such thing is not really good, parse your json data and fill it in a Class with what suites your case (like a class with 2 String memebers) then in the adapter just read from arraylist and simply use : `item.getVal1()`, `item.getVal2()`

Comment: Thanks for yout suggestion. I will try that. But I will have to modify my whole project for this

Comment: if this is some homework, you can just fix this as is, and in future consider better approach, but if this is a long term running project, it's better to be well structured and build, because one day, maybe a week later you will need to open this adapter class and then you will be like o_O what is this! :) my advice if you want to fix as is, you better prepare the arraylist with all-valid values before passing it to the adapter, so the adapter read values and populate views to prevent such empty views.

Comment: I understood your point. I will rebuild this as soon as I get some leisure time..

Comment: Could you post your customListview.xml file?

Comment: yes i did edit my post now

Comment: Is there a way like returning null in the else part of adapter class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just override getCount() inside your adapter and set the list length

```
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return myArray.size() / 2;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As @nbaroz mentioned in his answer you should override getCount() and return a custom value based on the content inside of myArray. Further more, it seems that since you only want your ListView to contain two rows you should only return 2 from getCount(). This way it will always only have two cells.

Based on what I understand from your description, you are trying to create a layout similar to the Play store; where you have several rows and in each row you have several individual columns. This can be done with only one data structure (ArrayList or LinkedList) to make the design easier. You would do this by having the data structure length be the amount of rows (this is better than hard-coding a value) you want to display. The items inside of the data structure would be of a custom object type that contains the data necessary for populating the columns inside of each row.

Example Custom ListView item object:

```
public class MyCustomRowObject {

public Column column1;
public Column column2;
public Column column2;
public Column getColumn1() {
return column1;
}
public Column getColumn2() {
return column2;
}
public Column getColumn3() {
return column3;
}
```

Inside of getView(...) you would get a reference of MyCustomRowObject and create your custom list item that contains the individual views for the columns of the row. Once the list item is inflated, use the data from MyCustomRowObject reference to populate the views data fields and return the list item. Viola!

**Also note**

This will incur a lot of overhead inflating all of these views so you definitely will want to using the view recycling pattern if you have any content that scroll of screen. Personally, I would use the recycling pattern always even if I don't have a lot of list data because it makes it future proof.